# wishing something at a moment in the past

Tags: conditional-constructions

Someone wrote:

> Over the last days , I’ve read a couple of my friends’ entries on the web about how tremendously picturesque places look in snowy winter, and I wish it snowed and got colder in Warsaw too.

I refined it to:

> Over the past few days, I’ve read a couple of entries from my friends about how picturesque places look in a snowy winter, and I wished it would snow and get colder in Warsaw too.

For the last part, I thought to mention a wish in a moment in the past, he should use "wished" plus "would", is it right?

Answer (score 4):

The verb **snowed** in the original is not incorrect. But it is not a wish in the past. It is a general wish.  A wish about the past would be "I wish it had snowed..."  A wish wished in the past would be "I wished (back then) that it would snow|snowed here..." and a wish wished in the past concerning a past earlier than the wish:  "I wished that it had snowed..."

> I wish it would snow here more often.
>
> I wish it snowed here more often.

Both are idiomatic. It doesn't snow in the location in question as often as the speaker would like it to snow.

Past general wish:

> I wished it would snow here more often.
>
> I wished it snowed here more often.

It *hadn't snowed* there as often as the speaker *would have liked* it to snow.

Past wish about a past earlier than the wish:

> As a young man I wished that it had snowed more often during my childhood. But as an older man, I am content when the sun shines.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on when you are wishing, and the time frame of the thing you are wishing for.  All of these are grammatically correct, but express different "wishes":

> I wish it would snow. (I want it to snow soon)
>
> I wish it had snowed. (It would be nice if it snowed before now)
>
> I wished it would snow. (At some time in the past I wanted it to snow)
>
> I wished it had snowed. (At some time in the past I thought it would have been nice had it previously snowed).

So, again, is are you wishing in the past, or are you wishing about a past event?  You can do either, or both.